# Deploy Django project on IIS via Helicon Zoo

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, graphite, heliconzoo

I have been struggling to have an existing Django project （Graphite webapp it is) on windows IIS via Helicon Zoo. So far I really just guess and try on every step but still can't make it work. Could anyone point me to any helpful manual or article? Thanks very much.

Django project: [Graphite-web](https://github.com/graphite-project/graphite-web) - yes, managed to port Graphite carbon, whisper and webapp on windows, but webapp now is only runnable with django-admin.py runserver

Win8 64bit, Python2.7 32bit

manage.py and grahpite.settings is in c:\graphite\webapp\graphite

Regards

James

Comment: Can you get a little more specific and localize the problem? Graphite-web is a big thing, you know.

Comment: @erbdex Any articles or personal experiences that are about 'how to' insall Django project via Helicon Zoo will be great help. (happens in my case it is Graphte-web and win8 64bit with Python2.7 32bit)

Comment: `1.` i can tell you all about Graphite installation on GNU/Linux. `2.` i have no clues about Helicon Zoo. `3.` But nevertheless, where exactly, in Helicon Zoo are you getting stuck?

Comment: @erbdex firstly thanks for quick response =) I got a problem now is I had the django project runnning as a django website within Helicon's dev env (as told it is express IIS embedded?), but trying hard to find a way to put the website onto IIS server (eg. local IIS server)

Comment: i recommend you first learn the parts that are in [play](http://serverfault.com/questions/9121/how-to-explain-django-python-installation-to-python-newbie-running-a-shared-iis) and then move onto [hosting](http://codesmartinc.com/2013/04/12/running-django-in-iis7iis8/) [django on IIS](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoOnWindowsWithIISAndSQLServer)

Comment: In GNU/Linux, a module connects python with the web-server- mod_wsgi, uwsgi etc. Graphite, which is built over the django framework sits on the web-server as a virtualhost. The flow will be similar. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We tried to install Graphite webapp out of curiosity and my colleague managed to do this (while I lost my patience collecting all Graphite requirements).

- So to install it first you need to install "Zoo -> Templates -> Python project"  in the location where you want this web site. Request is so all startup scripts did their job and virtualenv is created so you should see welcome Python project page.
- Now copy all your Graphite files into this web site's folder. When you asked to overwrite some files please be wise, like don't overwrite web.config file as it is needed.
- Modify prefix line in setup.cfg as follows:

  prefix = $APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH
- Modify  <environmentVariables> section of web.config as follows:

  <environmentVariables>
                    <add name="VIRTUAL_ENV" value="%APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH%.env" />
                    <add name="PATH" value="%APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH%\venv\Scripts;%PATH%" />
                    <add name="PYTHONPATH" value="%APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH%\venv\lib\site-packages;%APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH%\venv\lib;%APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH%;%APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH%\webapp\graphite" />
                    <add name="DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" value="settings" />
                    <add name="ERROR_LOG_DIR" value="log" />

(sorry for formatting, it is all stackoverflow)

- Then launch Start->Helicon->Zoo->Helicon Zoo Manager, select your web site and click on either Start IDE or Start Web Console button to start console for the virtualenv of the web site. Please use this console to run all python commands so the virtualenv is used.
- Run "python setup.py install" using Zoo console.
- Now the hardest part - download and install Graphite webapp requirements. Some of them may be installed using "pip install" command (don't forget to use Zoo console for it. Others require to be downloaded separately and have some pre-historic installers that can be user only for global installations. Many of them can then be copied under web site virtualenv manually so you can even restore Zoo application portability. Or leave it as is if you don't plan to move application to another server.

After that you should be able to run Graphite with "django-admin.py runserver" from Zoo console. If it works then it should work as IIS web site from Zoo as well.

If you have further questions please contact [Helicon Tech support](http://support.helicontech.com/)